# Problem with broadcom wireless driver on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom, b43

Yes I realize there are tons of material on the subject no I did not read them all.
Now I have gone through good few of the answers and it got me as far as system finding the drivers on its own and trying to install them through Software and updates / additional drivers section.
Problem is it starts download but than even if left for 15 hours it just doesn't download them once you click apply changes it just sits there on about 5% mark.
Have any of you linux magicians can come up with idiot proof solution for complete ignorant like my self had linux for 24h.

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
    DeviceName: Realtek Gigabit Network Connection
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:3660]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:365e]
    Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: And are you connected to internet?

Comment: Yes via ethernet cable

Comment: You can refer to this thread(http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and this script(https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) to debug this issue.

Comment: Well as I have mentioned i am an ignorant in matters of linux and I assume the fix seem obvious to all of you. But thank you for help all is working. See you when ill become entirely stupid again 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

The wifi should work.